# Access internal file in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, path

I'm rookie in code igniter, what I want is get file path to internal config file, my database.php that located in ./application/config/database.php. How can I do access into my file? I'm using file helper, but cannot find what path must I submitted on parameter.

Comment: use `$path = APPPATH.'config/database.php';`

Answer (score 0):

If you open index.php, you'll see you have APPPATH and BASEPATH defined.

So you want something like

```
$path = APPPATH . 'config/database.php';
```